# How to implemet Start()-like functionallity in a non-Monobehaviour class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here we have two classes, `A` and `B`.

`A` class is *Monobehaviour*, and `B` class is *non-Monobehaviour*.

Both classes have a method called `Initialize()`.

Class `A` can be called from `Start()`, but class `B` must be called after externally create an instance of `B`.

What I want here is '**How to implement a function like `Start()` inside `B`**'.

Because sometimes I forget to call `Initialize()` from externally.

---

The `Initialize()` method does the following:

```cs
public class Popup : IObjectPooling
{
  private IObjectPooling popup;

  public void Initialize()
  {
    popup = new Popup();
  }
}
```

---

#### Solved

Foolish, I realized late that there is no magic.

We separated the `new Popup()` part, which is the problematic part in the `Initialize()` method.

```cs
public class Popup : IObjectPooling
{
  private IObjectPooling popup;

  public Popup() {}

  public Popup(Popup popup)
  {
    this.popup = popup;
    Initialize();
  }

  public void Initialize()
  {
    //...
  }
}
```

```cs
[SerializeField] private Popup popup = new(new Popup());
```

Comment: Are there any dependencies of `B` to UnityEngine? The default case would be calling `Initialize()` from Constructor of `class B`

Comment: What led you to determine you cannot call an instance method from a constructor?

Comment: @hijinxbassist When called from the constructor, it goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: You are already handling this in a similar fashion to Start.  At the simplest level there is a collection of said objects, those objects have their function called by some "external" code.  Start is not magic, it gets called (albeit in a different way) from some "external" code.  You could add a CreateInstance method that calls Initialize for you, but of course you need to remember to call that method.

Comment: If you can change the Initialize signature, you could add a bool to indicate if the inner popup object needs to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unity Messages**

Unity's `Start` method (and all Message methods) makes use of `Component.SendMessage` internally to know when those specific message methods need to be called.  It then uses `Reflection` to find the appropriate method (if declared) and invoke it.  This creates a significant amount of overhead and work compared to a single call to `Initialize`.  You can implement this type of system if you believe it is the appropriate direction, or simply for learning purposes.

**Alternative Solutions**

If you can change the signature of the `Initialize` method, you can add a boolean to indicate if the inner Popup object should be created.

```
public class Popup : IObjectPooling
{
    private IObjectPooling popup;

    public Popup()
    {
        Initialize();
    }
    public Popup(bool initialize)
    {
        if (initialize)
        {
            Initialize();
        }
    }

    public void Initialize(bool initialize = true)
    {
        if (initialize)
        {
            popup = new Popup(false);
        }
    }
}
```

If this is not possible due to the interface or external factors, you could create a method that creates the instance and initializes it.

```
public static Popup CreateInstance()
{
    var popup = new Popup();

    popup.Initialize();

    return popup;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and effort to reply. I got the idea from the alternative you provided and solved the problem :)

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad you were able to figure out a way to resolve the issue.  If you wouldn't mind, please include your final approach (either as an answer or in your question), it may help others in the future.  Cheers!

Comment: Updated the post. Thank you again once!